# Adblock to prevent employees from accidentally clicking malicious ads

Tags: corporate-policy

Our Company allows browsing without restriction such as news, fb, twitter, blogs etc.

Would it make sense to have employees install Adblock or similar plugins to prevent (accidentally) clicking malicious ads?

If not, what are common measures exist apart from standard employee awareness training.

Comment: Make sense to what company? In what industry? This is opinion-based.

Comment: You don't seem to know why 'malicious ads' would cause compromises to your security? What about 'malicious' emails, and websites, and hardware, and applications? If you don't have a threat model there's no way we can discuss the policy that best addresses it.

Comment: Depending upon the vulnerability being exploited, the employees don't actually have to click on anything. Flash exploits come to mind.

Comment: In this day in age, I would say yes, absolutely.  And not only to have employees install an ad-blocker, but to make it a part of your standard configuration and push them out automatically.

Comment: I personally ended up installing an ad blocker because of the "colorful" ads commonly displayed alongside the web comics I read with my morning coffee/tea. So there's other benefits as well. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not needed but Its generally a good idea, malwaretising is quite common nowadays, plus most of users will probably appreciate the lack of ads. However, it may not prevent any infections at all if you have other things setup correctly (sandboxing, not using flash and java in browsers etc.)

But instead of forcing users to install them you can use stuff like Firefox ESR with CCK2(http://decentsecurity.com/enterprise/#/ublock-for-firefox-deployment/). Which would be a cleaner options.